# How to call element.onload inside AJAX sucess function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, height

I am uploading a image using AJAX in php codeignitor and on  upload return a JSON response containing path of uploaded image, then i insert that path into a img tag for preview

Now what i want to do is get the height and width of rendered img tag after updating its path, but the problem is i am getting a 0 always so please somebody help me out here

here is my JS

```js
function uploadAd(){
    // console.log($('#uploadedPDF').prop('files'));
    var file_data = $('#uploadedAdFile').prop('files')[0];
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('uploadedAdFile', file_data);
    // alert(form_data);
    $.ajax({

      url: BASE_URL+'home/uploadAdFile', // point to server-side PHP script
      dataType: 'json',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: form_data,
      type: 'post',
      async: false,
      success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
          if(data.status == -1){
            // If file extension Validation failed
            $('#uploadedAdFileMsg').html(data.msg);
            $('#uploadedAdFileMsg').removeClass('hidden');
            $('#uploadedAdFilePreview').addClass('hidden');
          }
          else{
            // If file extension Validation passed
            $('#uploadedAdFilePreview').attr('src', data.path); // Render file in img tag

            $('#uploadedAdFileMsg').addClass('hidden');
            $('#uploadedAdFilePreview').removeClass('hidden');

            console.log(document.getElementById('uploadedAdFilePreview').naturalWidth);
            // console.log()
          }
      },
      complete: function(){
        console.log('Complte '+document.getElementById('uploadedAdFilePreview').naturalWidth);
      }
    }).done(function(){
      console.log('Done '+document.getElementById('uploadedAdFilePreview').naturalWidth);
    });
  }
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    console.log('AJAX '+document.getElementById('uploadedAdFilePreview').naturalWidth);
  })
```

as you can see I inserted get height code in various places but no luck

PS: I used clientHeight, height, naturalHeight as well but still got 0

so what I concluded is the height function is called before the img tag rendered its content hence it shows a 0

so can I include a onload type of function inside a AJAX success function ??

thanks

Comment: have you tried hardcoding an image into the elements that hold your ads. if the image elements still have 0 height, then you probably need to fix up some css so the element will have some height to render the images. After you fix up this, then your javascript should be working fine.

Comment: Would perhaps be easier to not bloat the client-side logic with this, but just get the image dimensions server-side (`getimagesize`), and then return width and height in the JSON structure ...?

Comment: @Tyler there is no problem with the CSS, i got the correct height and width from my browser developer console after AJAX request.

Comment: @CBroe but i wanna know how to solve this using Js :)

Comment: You don’t need to use document.getElement... - you can simply get the DOM element via `$('#foo')[0]`

Comment: but that was'nt working

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it :D ,

actually i was using onload on a Jquery returned object which is wrong , it should be used on `document.getElement` , so then i put a

`element.onload = function(){ getHeight(); }`

inside my success function os AJAX, and it worked :)